# DateDiff giving me the wrong answer

Tags: vb.net

The function for getting the difference in days between two days is giving me a wrong answer here...What could i be doing wrong???

```
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate("28/1/2011"), CDate("31/1/2011"))
```

Comment: What answer is it giving you?

Comment: its giving me 2 instead of 3...

Answer (score 1):

For me, it returns `3`.

Which is the correct answer according to the documentation on [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

What were you expecting??

Comment: Odd. Possibly CDate might interpret date strings differently due to regional settings? Try checking what the CDate calls are returning?